# How can I apply a function to each row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I am pretty new to coding so this may be simple, but none of the answers I've found so far have provided information in a way I can understand.

I'd like to take a column of data and apply a function (a x e^bx) where a > 0 and b < 0. The (x) in this case would be the float value in each row of my data.

See what I have so far, but I'm not sure where to go from here....

```py
def plot_data():

    # read the file
    data = pd.read_excel(FILENAME)

    # convert to pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['FP Signal'])

    # add a blank column to store the normalized data
    headers = ['FP Signal', 'Normalized']
    df = df.reindex(columns=headers)
    df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(1, 2))
    df['Normalized'] = df.apply(normalize(['FP Signal']), axis=1)
    print(df['Normalized'])
    # show the plot
    plt.show()

# normalization formula (exponential) = a x e ^bx where a > 0, b < 0
def normalize(x):
    x = A * E ** (B * x)
    return x
```

I can get this image to show, but not the 'normalized' data.

[image: Subplot image of raw data and normalized data]

Comment: Try `df['Normalized'] = df['FP Signal'].apply(normalize)`.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right formula? `a * e ** (b * x)` will return much bigger value.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is almost correct.

```py
# normalization formula (exponential) = a x e ^bx where a > 0, b < 0
def normalize(x):
    x = A * E ** (B * x)
    return x

def plot_data():

    # read the file
    data = pd.read_excel(FILENAME)

    # convert to pandas dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['FP Signal'])

    # add a blank column to store the normalized data
    headers = ['FP Signal', 'Normalized']
    df = df.reindex(columns=headers)
    df['Normalized'] = df['FP Signal'].apply(lambda x: normalize(x))
    print(df['Normalized'])
    df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(1, 2))
    # show the plot
    plt.show()
```

I changed `apply` row to the following: `df['FP Signal'].apply(lambda x: normalize(x))`.
It takes only the value on df['FP Signal'] because you don't need entire row. `lambda x` states current values assign to x, which we send to normalize.

You can also write `df['FP Signal'].apply(normalize)` which is more directly and more simple. Using lambda is just my personal preference, but many may disagree.

One small addition is to put `df.plot(subplots=True, layout=(1, 2))` after you change dataframe. If you plot before changing dataframe, you won't see any change in the plot. `df.plot` actually doing the plot, `plt.show` just display it. That's why `df.plot` must be after you done processing your data.

Comment: The lambda is unnecessary since it has the exact same signature as `normalize`.

Comment: Agree, it's just my personal preference. I'll edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to apply a function to a field

[pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas-series-map)

```py
s = pd.Series(['cat', 'dog', 'rabbit'])
s.map(lambda x: x.upper())
```

```
0       CAT
1       DOG
2    RABBIT
```